# Evaluating a List of Variables to a List of Their Values in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I am wondering how one can achieve the following. Suppose I have a list of variables that are bound by some `let` above. I would like to turn this list into a list of the values to which those variables are bound.

That is, suppose we have

```
(define make-plist-from-variables (variables)
  (let ((keys variables)
        (values (mapcar #'identity variables)))
    (if (eq (length keys) (length values))
     (make-plist keys values)
     nil))))
```

What can I use in place of `#'identity` to unpack those values properly?

At the moment, the following call produces the following output.

```
CL-USER> (let ((a 2) (b 3)) (make-plist-from-variables '(a b)))
(A A B B)
```

I would like it to be `(A 2 B 3)`

Comment: lexical variables have no accessible representation in CL.

Comment: you should not compare numbers with EQ. Use EQL or =.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be a macro because there is no way to fetch a variable's lexical value based on its symbol.

```
(defmacro make-plist-from-variables (&rest variables)
  (loop :for binding :in variables
        :collect `',binding :into result
        :collect binding :into result
        :finally (return `(list ,@result))))

(macroexpand-1 '(make-plist-from-variables a b))
; ==> (list 'a a 'b b) 

(let ((a 2) (b 3)) 
  (make-plist-from-variables a b))
; ==> (a 2 b 3)
```

**EDIT**

Implementation without `loop` using [`mapcan`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm):

```
(defmacro make-plist-from-variables (&rest variables)
  `(list ,@(mapcan (lambda (v) `(',v ,v)) variables))
```

Comment: Nice code, but you should explain *why* it has to be a macro (this is also in the other answer, but your answer should be understandable on its own).

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. Just did :)

Comment: Looks good. Is it possible to do it without using the `loop`?

Comment: Shouldn't we be facing the same issue within the lambda as we were in my code? That is, the function gets a variable. How is it aware of the variable's lexical value?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Inside the macro you only have data representing code. Not values. The funcion only manipulates symbols and it quotes it to get the symbol and not to get the value **in the result**. Within the macro `a` and `b` has no value since this happens before the code runs, perhaps when the file is compiled. If you pass a wrong variable to it it will expand without error, but the evaluation of the result in runtime later will fail.

Comment: Could you also explain how this part works? ``(',v ,v)` Particularly, I am wondering how the first argument turns into the variable name. Based on my understanding of backquote, it should return a quoted value of the variable as the key.

Comment: @MadPhysicist So since we are in a macro we only have lists and symbols. Thus the variable name is all we have. We produce new code that gets evaluated so `\`(',v ,v)` makes a quoted version and a bare version, eg.  `('b b)`, so that when evaluated in the final expansion you get the name, then the value.

Comment: That makes sense. I essentially answered it myself haha. I feel silly for asking it. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Functions don't have access to the lexical environment of their callers. 
More precisely, during evaluation you cannot access the values of lexical variables knowing only their symbols. Only macros have access to [environment objects](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_aad.htm).

#### Special variables

You can use dynamic binding:

```
(defun foo ()
  (declare (special a))
  (symbol-value 'a))

(let ((a 3))
  (declare (special a))
  (foo))

=> 3
```

In your case, you would collect the symbol along its value, by using [`SYMBOL-vaLUE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_symb_5.htm#symbol-value) on all your symbols.

Related to your question is how to dynamically bind variables to values where the variable names and/or values are known at evaluation time; see special operator [`PROGV`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_progv.htm).

#### Macros

You could obtain e.g. an association list by writing the following code:

```
(acons 'a a (acons 'b b nil))
```

Depending on the use case behind your question, you may want to have a macro that expands into such code, that references the variables you want to evaluate.